# When I'm translating the pages into Chinese or Japanese, the character will shown as normal

Tags: html, css

So I'm using the Vertical-RL writing mode in my wiki, and I was surprised that when I translating this page into Chinese or Japanese, that Chinese or Japanese character appears normal. Can you see why that happens? Here's the image link for more information:
[Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjesk.png)

The codes are as shown:

```css
.example {
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
word-wrap: break-word;
text-overflow: clip;
white-space: normal
}
```

```html
<h1 class="example">Hi guys, translate this into Chinese<h1>
```

I might be wrong, but test it on your coding software, and translate it.

by the CSS guy

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Azam. Please read [our guide to asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can provide us with more details. Are you using a common CMS or are you directly coding static HTML/CSS?

Comment: I think it's coding static because I used the wiki source editor, and yeah I forgot the code, here's the code: writing-mode: vertical-rl; word-wrap: break-word; text-overflow: clip; white-space: normal

Comment: OK, I'm still unsure but what your issue is, if your characters are shown as "normal", what is the problem? if they're not displaying correctly, can you elaborate on that? how should they look like?